# Proving $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(2x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)^{n}=x^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(2x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)^{n}=x^2$$ $\forall$ $x \ge 1$

My try:

For $x=1$ The proof is Trivial

If $x \gt 1$ we have by Binomial Theorem

$$\left(2x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)^{n}=2^nx-\frac{nx2^{n-1}}{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}+\frac{\binom{n}{2}x2^{n-2}}{x^{\frac{2}{n}}}-\cdots$$

Any way here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that 
$$\begin{align}\left(2x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)^{n}&=\left(2e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{n}}-1\right)^{n}=
\left(2\left(1+\frac{\ln(x)}{n}+o(1/n)\right)-1\right)^{n}\\
&=\left(1+\frac{\ln(x^2)}{n}+o(1/n)\right)^{n}\\
&=\exp\left(n\ln\left(1+\frac{\ln(x^2)}{n}+o(1/n)\right)\right)
\end{align}$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

This amounts to showing the limit of the log is equal to $2\log x$. We'll use *equivalence* of functions:

$$\qquad \log\left(2x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)^{n}=n\log\left(2x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)=\frac{\log\left(1+2(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)\right)}{\frac1n}\sim\frac{2(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)}{\frac 1n}.\qquad$$
Now $\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{x^h-1}h=\bigl(x^h\bigr)'_{h=0}=\bigl(x^h\log x\bigr)_{h=0}=\log x$, so the limit of the  log  is indeed $2\log x$.

Comment: You could also identify the logarithm as the difference quotient for $f(s)=\log(2x^s-1)$ at $s=0$ and use the chain rule to compute the derivative.

Comment: You're right, but using equivalence simplifies the computations. I use only tools/limits  from high-school (+ equivalence, of course).